gdb make breakpoint but not show int3 instruction
I was learning about int 3 instruction and breakpoint in gdb.
But i found something strange.
My c code as follows:
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int a = 4;
        a += 3;
        int b = 4;
        int c = b*a;
        printf("%d\n", c);
        return 0;
}


then compile it:
gcc ./test.c

then use gdb, output as follows:
[xxx@xxxx 23:29:23 ~]
$ gdb ./a.out
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(No debugging symbols found in ./a.out)
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/heyuanhong/a.out
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
28
[Inferior 1 (process 179733) exited normally]
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000555555555149 <+0>:     endbr64
   0x000055555555514d <+4>:     push   %rbp
   0x000055555555514e <+5>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000555555555151 <+8>:     sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x0000555555555155 <+12>:    mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555158 <+15>:    mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
   0x000055555555515c <+19>:    movl   $0x4,-0xc(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555163 <+26>:    addl   $0x3,-0xc(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555167 <+30>:    movl   $0x4,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x000055555555516e <+37>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000555555555171 <+40>:    imul   -0xc(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000555555555175 <+44>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555178 <+47>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x000055555555517b <+50>:    mov    %eax,%esi
   0x000055555555517d <+52>:    lea    0xe80(%rip),%rax        # 0x555555556004
   0x0000555555555184 <+59>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000555555555187 <+62>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000055555555518c <+67>:    call   0x555555555050 <printf@plt>
   0x0000555555555191 <+72>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000555555555196 <+77>:    leave
   0x0000555555555197 <+78>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b *0x0000555555555171
Breakpoint 1 at 0x555555555171
(gdb) x/1bx 0x0000555555555171
0x555555555171 <main+40>:       0x0f
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000555555555149 <+0>:     endbr64
   0x000055555555514d <+4>:     push   %rbp
   0x000055555555514e <+5>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000555555555151 <+8>:     sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x0000555555555155 <+12>:    mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555158 <+15>:    mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
   0x000055555555515c <+19>:    movl   $0x4,-0xc(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555163 <+26>:    addl   $0x3,-0xc(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555167 <+30>:    movl   $0x4,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x000055555555516e <+37>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000555555555171 <+40>:    imul   -0xc(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000555555555175 <+44>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555178 <+47>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x000055555555517b <+50>:    mov    %eax,%esi
   0x000055555555517d <+52>:    lea    0xe80(%rip),%rax        # 0x555555556004
   0x0000555555555184 <+59>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000555555555187 <+62>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000055555555518c <+67>:    call   0x555555555050 <printf@plt>
   0x0000555555555191 <+72>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000555555555196 <+77>:    leave
   0x0000555555555197 <+78>:    ret
End of assembler dump.

first, i print assemble code in main function, then i set breakpoint in adderess 0x0000555555555171. after that i try to print value of 0x0000555555555171, and i print assemble code again.
my question is why after created a breakpoint in adderess 0x0000555555555171 ( imul   -0xc(%rbp),%eax), the int 3(opcode is 0xcc) instrction not show?
I think adderess 0x0000555555555171 should be 0xcc, because i just set breakpoint, does not hit the breakpoint.
My OS is ubuntu 22.04, gcc version is 11.4.0, CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-14900KF

I think gdb removes the breakpoints when the process is stopped.

Likely on your platform you can read text section at runtime. For example printf("%02X\n", *((unsigned char *)main));. If you load program in gdb, then break main, run, cont, output will be CC - this is opcode for int3. During "normal" run output will differ. Disclaimer: casting function pointer to data pointer is UB

Int 3 is used for software breakpoints. In your scenario, gdb might decide to use a hardware breakpoint, which doesn't require patching the code and would also explain why you don't see the expected value.

@Joachim hey, I used info b to print breakpoint information, show breakpoint type is breakpoint, not hardware breakpoint

@ssbssa but i haven't run debugger, just set breakpoint

@dimich Sorry, it's not output CC, does it work on your machine?

@Blueha Yes, on my machine it displays CC when breakpoint at main is set in gdb, and 48 when it is not set (or run without gdb). CPU i5-8365U, gdb version 15.1.

@Blueha the same is true in reverse, the breakpoint is only set once the program starts/continues (if the program wasn't even started, there is nothing where gdb could put int 3 into, since it only does that in the target process).

@ssbssa is correct that normally GDB only inserts breakpoints at the point the inferior is started, and removes them again once the inferior has stopped.  You can set breakpoint always-inserted on to have GDB leave breakpoints in the inferior even when it has stopped (so long as the process still exists), but even then you'll not (easily) get GDB to show the breakpoint bytes ... because GDB assumes that you don't want to see that, and goes out of its way to hide those from you, even for the breakpoint always-inserted case.  Every read is filtered to hide software breakpoints.

As has been mentioned, if you really want to see the software breakpoints then you will need to get the inferior to read that memory itself as GDB is not able to hide the software breakpoints in this case.

To summarize what others have answered in comments:

Not every type of breakpoint requires overwriting the program text with 0xCC opcode for int3 instruction
GDB only inserts breakpoints when it is about to transfer control to the inferior (being debugged) program and removes them after GDB gets control (i.e. when the program stops at the breakpoint). This is controlled by set breakpoint always-inserted on (which defaults to off).
Even when breakpoints are left inserted, GDB disas pretends they aren't there, since normally you want to see the original disassembly, not the mangled picture you would get where the original disassembly is overwritten at random with 0xCC opcodes (rendering the remainder of overwritten instruction either meaningless or just wrong).
If you really really want to observe the code as modified by GDB, you can have the inferior (while it is running) copy the code bytes to a separate buffer. When the breakpoint is hit, you can use disas to examine instructions in that buffer, and you would see the actual instructions, with the int3 opcode sprinkled in there.

